# How to remove unused dependencies from a clojure leiningen project?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I have a leiningen Clojure project and there are a lot of dependencies in it. I want to automatically remove all of the dependencies which are not being used. How do I do this? Please help.

Comment: Are you asking how to remove old dependencies from the build?  Or are you asking for a way to determine which dependencies (in project.clj) are actually no longer referenced in any of the project's source files?

Answer (score 5):

Bare hands:
comment the dependency entry you suspect to be useless using `#_` (eg. `#_[org.ow2.asm/asm-all "4.2"]`) and try to compile.

With tool:
[Eastwood](https://github.com/jonase/eastwood) is a clojure linter implemented as a leiningen plugin. It will do what you need using its `:unused-namespaces` option (not enabled by default). I'll let you head to the doc.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will definitely try this.